# delete email addresses that contain domain names in another column with this domain list

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with with one column each .Table one has a column 1 with email addresses(Emails) ,table 2 has column 2 with domains(domains) that are contained in the email addresses.This column 2 also contains emails that should be deleted.
I want to delete email addresses from column 1 that contain the domain names and email addresses in column 2 .
These two tables were imported from text files into a table in a db on mssql
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your attempt at this? This seems like a basic SQL operation.

Comment: A
Database
a.almatri@familybankbh.com
a.alomani@kpc.com.kw
a.deborja@samsung.com
a.fahmy@abudhabiaviation.com
a.horizon@eim.ae

Answer (score 0):

```
delete 
t1 
from table1 as t1 
where 
exists(select 1 from table2 as t2.column2 = right(t1.column1, len(t1.column1) - Charindex('@', t1.column1)) )
```

This is a very ugly query that should be very slow with a large table1. I would recommend you to add a persited computed column in table1 that would contain this computed domain using the ugly expression:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD computedDomain as right(t1.column1, len(t1.column1) - Charindex('@', t1.column1)) persisted;
```

Then, you can add an index on the computed column if necessary

Comment: Hello Stephane , this is a clearer description of what I have